# wrong output in vs code but correct in online compiler

Tags: c++

## To check Armstrong number or not

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float countdigit(int n)
{
    float count = 0;
    while (n)
    {
        count++;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return count;
}

bool Armstrong(int input, int exponent)
{
    int temp = input, ans = 0, rem;
    while (temp)
    {
        rem = temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
        ans = ans + pow(rem, exponent);
    }
    if (ans == input)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "enter: ";
    cin >> num;

    float digit = countdigit(num);

    cout << Armstrong(num, digit);

    return 0;
}
```

The code when given 153 as an input which is an armstrong number should print 1.
But when running in vs code gives 0 (wrong output) and when running the same in an online c++ compiler gives 1 (correct output).
[Shows the output of the same code both in vs code and online c++ compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKRTV.jpg)

Comment: You should not use floating-point numbers when solving integer problems.

Comment: Why `countdigit` return float and not an integer type? calculations on floating point are inaccurate and may be different on different CPU.

Comment: Instead of `pow()` (a floating point function), use an approach to compute an integer power.   That will (apart from potential for overflow that needs to be managed) be exact.   There are various approaches (plenty online) to do that relatively efficiently (usually not as fast as `pow()` but, in this case, you need an exact result).

Comment: changed float to int still the same problem persists.

Comment: changing your function to return `int` is not sufficient,because `pow` is still using floats

Comment: make your power function like this:  `int power(int n, int exp){ return exp==0?1:n*power(n,exp-1); }` if needed results larger than `int` use `unsigned` or `int64_t`

Comment: @Rayan Find an example that doesn't work and then print out the value that pow returns like this `cout << (int)pow(rem, exponent);` (the `(int)` cast is very important). The results might surprise you.

Comment: @Rayan Basically the problem is that you are assuming that `pow` will give an exact result, for example that `pow(10, 5)` must be `100000` but that is not true, it could be `99999.99999999` (for example) and that messes up your calculation.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It worked.